# Using local.storage for weblinks

Tags: html, input, local-storage

I have done a good deal of searching and can't find exactly what I am looking for and I am very new at HTML/JavaScript.

I have a basic website that has a home and away link for my camera server (MotionEye). I want a few other people to use the website so I would like to be able to change the link locations from within the site for each user. What is the easiest way to have the ability to change the home/away links? I am hosting with AWS so PHP is not an option according to the AWS documentation. I am thinking local storage makes the most sense but I can not find a way to make it work.

Here is my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
<title>MotionEYE</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--top motion eye text-->
<div class="banner">motion eye</div>

<!--settings icon-->
<div class="container"><a href="settings.html"></div>
    <div class="bar1"></div>
<div class="bar2"></div>
<div class="bar3"></div>
</div>  

<!-- Side navigation -->
<div class="sidenav">
    <a href="home_link_here">Home</a>
    <a href="away_link_here">Away</a>
<!--button place holders-->     
    <a href="#" >Arm</a>
    <a href="#" >Disarm</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My index.css file:

```
.banner {

background-color:#414141;
background-attachment:fixed;
font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
color: #818181;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
text-transform:uppercase;
width:100%;      
}

body {

background-color:#414141;
background-attachment:fixed;
font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
text-transform:uppercase;
width:100%;     
}

.container {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {

width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #111;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Portrait layout (default) */
.app {
color: 818181;
position: fixed;
height: 100;
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
font-size:35px;
}
/* Landscape layout (with min-width) */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
.app {
    background-position:left center;
    padding:75px 0px 75px 170px;  /* padding-top + padding-bottom + text area = image height */
    margin:-90px 0px 0px -198px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height */
                                  /* offset horizontal: half of image width and text area width */
}
}

h1 {
font-size:24px;
font-weight:normal;
margin:0px;
overflow:visible;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
}

.event {
border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:12px;
margin:0px 30px;
padding:2px 0px;
}

.event.listening {
background-color:#333333;
display:block;
}

.event.received {          
background-color:#4B946A;
display:none;
}

@keyframes fade {
from { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.4; }
to { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.4; }
to { opacity: 1.0; }
}

.blink {
animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
} 

/* The sidebar menu */
.sidenav {
height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
width: 115px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
top: 90;
right: 0;
background-color: #111; /* Black */
overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
padding-top: 20px;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
}
```

I would like to either have an identical settings page that can change the link locations for home/away links on the index page or, if it's easier, make it all work in one page. Ideally I used input text boxes that can change the href links for home/away. The simpler, the better. This is a personal project for me and a couple people I helped install cameras and I really have no idea how to build a website. Please excuse any code mistakes I made as I just used google to get as far as I am now.

Here is the test page I did using the jQuery method outlined below. The links work but the input boxes do not.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="home-text-field" placeholder="Update the Home Link" />
<input type="text" id="away-text-field" placeholder="Update the Away Link" />

<button type="button" id="submit" />Save Links</button> 

<a id="home-link" href="http://www.google.com">Home</a>
<a id="away-link" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Away</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  let homeText = '';
  let awayText = '';

 //Get the DOM elements for the two links
 let $homeLink = $("#home-link");
 let $awayLink = $("#away-link");

    // Listen for changes to the text fields by their ID
$("#home-text-field").change(function(e) {
    homeText = $(this).text();
});

$("#away-text-field").change(function(e) {
       awayText = $(this).text();
})

    // When the button is clicked update the links
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $homeLink.attr('href') = homeText;
        $awayLink.attr('href') = awayText
 })
})

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see some code of yours. An example of how a portion of your site looks like and how you want it to behave would help. Please see [mcve].

Comment: PHP is an option in AWS.

Comment: Amazon static web hosting does not allow for PHP according to this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Answer (score 0):

You can update links dynamically with JQuery. If you give your links `id` tags you can easily select them with javascript and update the locations dynamically or with a text box. First you need to include JQuery into your page so

Add this to the bottom of your HTML file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then give an `id` attribute to your links like so:

```
<a id="home-link" href="home_link_here">Home</a>
<a id="away-link" href="away_link_here">Away</a>
```

You can also add some text fields to update the links:

```
<input type="text" id="home-text-field" placeholder="Update the Home Link" />
<input type="text" id="away-text-field" placeholder="Update the Away Link" />
<button type="button" id="submit" />Save Links</button>
```

And then tie it all together with some JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   let homeText = '';
   let awayText = '';

   //Get the DOM elements for the two links
   let $homeLink = $("#home-link");
   let $awayLink = $("#away-link");

    // Listen for changes to the text fields by their ID
   $("#home-text-field").change(function(e) {
       homeText = $(this).text();
   });

   $("#away-text-field").change(function(e) {
       awayText = $(this).text();
   })

    // When the button is clicked update the links
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $homeLink.attr('href') = homeText;
        $awayLink.attr('href') = awayText
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.  I did a test page putting everything you gave me together and the links work but the submit button does not change the links  I used google and yahoo as the starting links then trying to change them to my camera server links with no luck maybe I put it together wrong?  Take a look I added it to the initial post.